# `ido-find-file` always trigger `ido-reread-directory`

Tags: tramp, ido, advice

Tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907035/1374078), but did not work on Emacs27

```
(defadvice ido-find-file (before auto-refresh-ido nil activate)
(setq ido-rescan t))
```

Also tried but did not work because when `ido-reread-directory` is triggered ido mode is not active.

```
(advice-add 'ido-find-file :before ido-reread-directory)
```

Is there a way to force `ido-find-file` always trigger `C-l` (`ido-reread-directory`)? I mostly need this in tramp mode because files/folders do not update timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way Ido is structured, this is going to be very hard (if not impossible) to accomplish by advising `ido-find-file` or related functions.

What you should do instead is set `ido-max-dir-file-cache` to `0`.

Comment: It mostly works, there is a delay for cache to update file's existence.